# sed Remove lines between two patterns (excluding end pattern)

Tags: sed

given text like

```
_adsp           TXT "dkim=all"
VVKMU6SE3C2MF88BG4DJQAECMR9SIIF0 NSEC3 1 1 10 C4F407437E8EA4C5 (
                175MCHR31K25LP89OVJI5LCE0JA2N2AP
                A MX TXT AAAA RRSIG SPF )
            RRSIG   NSEC3 7 3 1800 (
                20200429171433 20200330161758 11672 example.com
                H3l26qmtkuiFZCeSYCCAo5krFE3gjM0I8UeQ9jhj3STy
                X6fM0YizCHEuv4VZynOJGJc1XJnHRHI+p7yLlZ+OVseK
                UfIkPVP+VOmlerwozEpM+Tnt8evwnMTDbcn0zxf/6YJx
                kZeO2AszWkRZ0bctqW7INYo8YuyyuTSxSr8se27fiaPA
                4GXQymepGgv/JGqargzHbyhhkDhENmNo7Qwkjl+a0kI4
                6qqKcEWCsDvnlYUQiDFzc5oRs2j7TT9uybTfwUDQxV+t
                MQFMhzu7LNbRIUuOb16sAEGSdl9mWQ4sZRJ9wuXJWbso
                G+3tY0pBbq4ffScz/JKcrJ0qAuBF1F5JcQ== )
$TTL 1800
```

I want to get rid by the part with the "(not beginning with whitespace) NSEC3 " until the first line not beginning with a whitespace character.
resulting

```
_adsp           TXT "dkim=all"
$TTL 1800
```

in the example.
I tried `sed  '/^[^\s].*\sNSEC3\s/,/^[^\s]/d;' filename` but that doesn't work as expected, example results in

```
_adsp           TXT "dkim=all"
                H3l26qmtkuiFZCeSYCCAo5krFE3gjM0I8UeQ9jhj3STy
                X6fM0YizCHEuv4VZynOJGJc1XJnHRHI+p7yLlZ+OVseK
                UfIkPVP+VOmlerwozEpM+Tnt8evwnMTDbcn0zxf/6YJx
                kZeO2AszWkRZ0bctqW7INYo8YuyyuTSxSr8se27fiaPA
                4GXQymepGgv/JGqargzHbyhhkDhENmNo7Qwkjl+a0kI4
                6qqKcEWCsDvnlYUQiDFzc5oRs2j7TT9uybTfwUDQxV+t
                MQFMhzu7LNbRIUuOb16sAEGSdl9mWQ4sZRJ9wuXJWbso
                G+3tY0pBbq4ffScz/JKcrJ0qAuBF1F5JcQ== )
$TTL 1800
```

so resuming printout way too early?

what do I miss?

thank you

P.S.:
you maybe see what I want to do is removing DNSSEC parts out of an named zone. didn't find any other way to remove RRSIG and NSEC3 entries, yet. If someone has an idea, I would appreciate that too.

Comment: `[\s]` matches an `[s]`. Also the `/^[^\s]/d;` will _remove_ the `$TTL 1800` line.

Answer (score 1):

`[\s]` matches a literal `\` or `s` characters. It doesn't match whitespace.

The `/^[^\s]/d;` (if `[\s]` would work as you expect) will also include removing the last line with non-leading whitespaces. I think you have to loop manually.

On the example you've given, the following seems to work:

```
sed -n '/^[^ \t].*\sNSEC3\s/{ :a; n; /^[^ \t]/bb; ba}; :b; p'
```

Comment: Why does OP get several lines deleted then?

Comment: Because `[\s]` matches `s`. `/^[^\s].*\sNSEC3\s/` - matches lines that do not start with \ or `s` and have `NSEC3`. So basically `[^\s]` matches a space.

Comment: Of course! I forgot about looking at the other side

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/^\S.*NSEC/{:a;n;/^\S/!ba};p' file
```

Turn off implicit printing by using the `-n` option.

Throw away lines between one starting with a non-space and containing the string `NSEC` and any lines not starting with a non-space.

Print all other lines.

Alternative:

```
sed '/^\S.*NSEC/,/^\S/{/^\S.*NSEC\|^\s/d}' file
```

Yet another alternative:

```
sed '/^\S.*NSEC/{:a;N;/\n\S/!ba;s/.*\n//}' file
```

And another:

```
sed '/^\S.*NSEC/{:a;N;/\n\S/!s/\n//;ta;D}' file
```

N.B. The first two solutions will delete lines regardless of a line delimiting the end of the deletions. Whereas the last two solutions will only delete lines if there is a line delimiting the end of the deletions.